# how to reset navigation onNewIntent

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, android-navigation

I have a share fragment receives a youtube share URL via intent and uses navigation the flow is:

```
ScanFragment -> PlaylistFragment
             -> VideoFragment
```

So the scan fragment parses the url and loads the data and then forwards to the relevant fragment to display the data

So if a user presses home on the `VideoFragment` or `PlaylistFragment` then the activity stay alive and navigation is not at its initial point `ScanFragment`

So if the user shares another URL then the intent comes via `onNewIntent` and the navigation needs to be reset so the URL can be routed to the scan fragment;

How can I ensure the navigation is reset to its initial state? I have tried navigating manually to scan fragment - but there seems to be latency and also the back stack isn't correct.

The nav is initialized in the `NavHostFragment`(`app:navGraph`)

How can i force the navigation to reset in `onNewIntent`?

EDIT:
so there where a couple of things i missed here: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-deep-link

I updated my nav graph to add the deepLink for my scan fragment

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/share_navigation_scan"
        android:name="uk.co.sentinelweb.cuer.app.ui.share.scan.ScanFragment"
        android:label="@string/sharenav_title_scan"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_scan">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_goto_playlist"
            app:destination="@id/share_navigation_playlist"
            app:launchSingleTop="true"
            app:popUpTo="@id/navigation_playlist"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />

        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_goto_playlist_item"
            app:destination="@id/share_navigation_playlist_item_edit"
            app:launchSingleTop="true"
            app:popUpTo="@id/navigation_playlist_item_edit"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />

        <deepLink app:uri="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={id}" />
        <deepLink app:uri="https://youtube.com/watch?v={id}" />
        <deepLink app:uri="https://m.youtube.com/watch?v={id}" />
        <deepLink app:uri="https://youtu.be/{id}" />
        <deepLink app:uri="https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list={id}" />
        <deepLink app:uri="https://youtube.com/playlist?list={id}" />
    </fragment>
```

and i have removed `android:launchMode="standard"` - seems like that should be right for navigation though.

and my `onNewIntent`

```
override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent) {
     super.onNewIntent(intent)
     navController.handleDeepLink(intent)
     checkIntent(intent)
}
```

checkIntent tries a few different way of ggetting the url from the intent and passing it down to the scan fragment

but still when i `checkIntent` the fragment is not ScanFragment -

I also tried removing `checkIntent` and getting the url in the onStart of `ScanFragment` - but still no joy.

So event with the `handleDeepLink` in `onNewIntent` (which i shouldnt need anyway according to the docs if it's standard launchmode ) - still the nav doesnt return to scan fragment for subsequent deeplink launches after the first one.

`activity` manifest entry

```
<activity
            android:name=".app.ui.share.ShareActivity"
            android:exported="true">

            <nav-graph android:value="@navigation/deeplink" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />

                <data android:scheme="http" />
                <data android:scheme="https" />
                <data android:host="youtu.be" />
                <data android:pathPattern="/" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />

                <data android:host="youtu.be" />
                <data android:path="/" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />

                <data android:host="youtube.com" />
                <data android:host="www.youtube.com" />
                <data android:host="m.youtube.com" />

                <data android:path="/watch" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />

                <data android:host="youtube.com" />
                <data android:host="www.youtube.com" />
                <data android:host="m.youtube.com" />

                <data android:path="/playlist" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: If you don't have any `launchMode` on your activity (which is what [the documentation specifically recommends](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-deep-link#handle)), then this is handled automatically for you. Why are you adding a launchMode at all?

Comment: i did have  `android:launchMode="standard"` - but i removed it and the behaviour is still the same.

Comment: so i missed some things here but it still doesn't work - have updated above

Comment: `onNewIntent` isn't even called when using the default `standard` launchMode. If that's still being called, them something else is wrong with your setup.

Comment: yes i don't understand - its definitely disabled in the manifest. There are intent filters on the `activity`. i out he activity config above.